# can users confirm their mailing list subscription by replying to the confirmation email?

Tags: civimail, mailing, inbound-email

Sorry in advance if this is an obvious question, but I'm not finding it in the documentation.

I've been testing the mailing list subscription function, and see that the default confirmation says "To confirm this subscription, reply to this email or click here."  Clicking the link works to confirm subscription, but replying to the confirmation (the reply-to address formatted like civicrmc.NN.NN.NNN@mydomain.org) doesn't work.

Where are these messages supposed to be handled? It doesn't seem to be bounce or email-to-activity processing (https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/civimail/#configuring-inbound-email-processing). My bounce processing is set up and working.

Is the message template incorrect? Or am I missing a configuration somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is handled by bounce processing (with the default mail account) and it should work. Is it possible that you just haven't waited long enough for your bounce processing cron job to run, which might be once an hour or so?

Comment: I added to the System Administrator guide a sentence explaining which email is used.

Comment: I thought about that, and did verify that the bounce processing job did run. Still isn't working.  But at least I know now where to start the troubleshooting.  And thanks for updating the docs! :-)